# When I write special latin1 characters to an utf-8 encoded mysql table, is that data lost?

Tags: mysql

When I write special latin1 characters, for example

á, é ã , ê

to an utf-8 encoded mysql table, is that data lost ?

The charset for that table is utf-8.

Is there any way to get that latin1 encoded rows back so I can convert to utf-8 and write back (this time in the right way)?

**Update**

I think I wasn't very specific about what I meant with "data". By data I mean the special characters, not the row.

When selecting, I still get the row and the fields, but with '?' instead of special latin1 characters. It is possible to recover those '?' and transform to the right utf8 ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the whole database (or a whole table) is affected, you can first verify that it is a Latin1-as-UTF8 charset problem with `SET NAMES Latin1`:

```
mysql> select txt from tbl;
+-----------+
| txt       |
+-----------+
| QuÃ©bec   |
| QuÃ©bec   |
+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET NAMES Latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select txt from tbl;
+---------+
| txt     |
+---------+
| Québec  |
| Québec  |
+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If this verifies, i.e. you get the desired data when using default charset Latin-1, then you can dump the whole table forcing `--default-character-set=latin1` so that a file will be created with the correct data, **albeit with the wrong charset specification**.

But now you can replace the header row stating

```
/*!40101 SET NAMES latin1 */;
```

with UTF8. Reimport the database and you're done.

If only *some* rows are affected, then it is much more difficult:

```
SELECT txt, CAST(CAST(txt AS CHAR CHARACTER SET Latin1) AS BINARY) AS utf8 FROM tbl;

+-----------+---------+
| txt       | utf8    |
+-----------+---------+
| QuÃ©bec   | Québec  |
+-----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

...but you have the problem of locating the affected rows. Some of the code points you might find with

```
WHERE txt LIKE '%Ã%'
```

but for the others, you'll have to sample manually.

Answer (score 3):

The data is not lost. See [this SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a7ba/1)

Comment: In the sql fiddle, how are your inserting the latin1 encoded chars? In the example I just see you inserting regular utf8 ones.

Answer (score 1):

The additional affected rows can be found using the following:

```
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE NOT HEX(column) REGEXP '^([0-7][0-9A-F])*$'
```